# Import ng2Translate into all modules without having to use a SharedModule

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

The [instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-translate) for the `ng2-translate` module mention easily adding `Translate` to a `SharedModule` that you import into your other modules, if you're working in a modular project and you want it to be available in all modules.

This actually isn't so easy, if your project isn't already using a SharedModule that all other modules import, and/or you don't want all modules to import your SharedModule.

Is there any other way of making `ng2Translate` available to all modules in your application? I had thought maybe importing it into **app.module.ts** but it seems like in their example, it's already imported into **app.module.ts** like so:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        HttpModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
            deps: [Http]
        })
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you import it in `the app.module.ts`, the providers of `TranslateModule` will be available to all your app. So you can use translation through the service everywhere, even in other modules.

However, to use pipes or directives in html templates, you have to import the module in each module where you want to use pipes/directives. I think you can't avoid that.